# Storing PDF In Database Or Hard Drive

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a webpage that stores Scanned PDF files. At the moment I store it in the Sql Database with as a varbinary.

I am redesigning everything from scratch and was thinking it may be more efficient to store the PDF's on the hard drive and just have a path..

The PDF collection, potentionally could get to 500gig+..

which is more efficient and what are the advantages either way?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Storing Images in DB - Yea or Nay?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3748/storing-images-in-db-yea-or-nay)

Comment: This has been discussed ad nauseum. You should consider images and PDF files the same way for the purposes of this discussion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look into using FILESTREAM to store the files in a database-accessible way on the file system: [Using FILESTREAM to Store BLOBs in the NTFS File System in SQL Server 2008](http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1489/using-filestream-to-store-blobs-in-the-ntfs-file-system-in-sql-server-2008/)

Answer (score 1):

I would use a persistent store such as AmazonS3. It's cheap, replicated, and if you change your database technology at some point in the future, it will be fairly easy. Instead of storing the files directly in your database, store the URL of the PDF on your AmazonS3 storage.